# Locally monotone Boolean function

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, boolean-functions, combinatorics

I am unable to understand the definition of locally monotone Boolean function which is defined in Gotsman and Linial, "[Spectral Properties of Threshold Functions](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~nati/PAPERS/gotsman_linial.pdf)", 1994, p. 40:

> A function $f$ is called *locally monotone* if it is increasing or decreasing in each variable.

Can somebody explain the definition with two examples (a function which is locally monotone and a function which is not)?

Comment: spectral properties of threshold functions by Gotsman and Linial, 1994.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example of a locally monotone function is $g(x,y) = x \cdot (1-y)$. In this example $g$ is monotone increasing in $x$ and monotone decreasing in $y$.

An example of a function that is not locally monotone is $h(x,y) = x \oplus y$.
Let's see why it is not locally monotone. Look at the $x$ variable. (1) It is neither monotone increasing in $x$ since $h(0,1) > h(1,1)$, (2) nor is it monotone decreasing in $x$ since $h(0,0) < h(1,0)$.

Locally monotone functions are called also [unate functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unate_function).

Comment: at the end it will be $h(0,0) < h(1,0)$

Comment: right, sorry. i just updated the answer